# How to tell where a function is coming from in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook

So I recently was looking over a code file I had downloaded as a tutorial a while back and I noticed a problem with a function called "next()".

I wanted to dig deeper but was unable to given I have about 20 imports and other than checking every single one of their (potential) next() functions to see if it is indeed the one I am looking for I do not know of a way to know where that function is coming from.

Sometimes IDE's will allow you to hover over the method/variable in question to gain insight into what is happening under the hood, but not with JN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the module from which the method was imported using the `__module__` attribute attached to this method.

For instance:

```py
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.__module__
'datetime'
>>> from itertools import count
>>> count.__module__
'itertools'
```